# Setting a private data member

Tags: c++, class, pointers, boolean

I have a private boolean data member (value) which is part of class Bar and I'm trying to access it with a pointer from another class Foo. However, when I try to access the data using a pointer it is like the data that I previously set has reset returning the wrong value.
Here is an example of what I am talking about, header file for class Bar:

```
class Foo;

class Bar {
private:
  bool value;

public:
  void read();
  bool isValue();
};
```

Here is an example of the source file.

```
 void Bar::read() { //setter method that sets value to true.
    value = true;
}

bool Bar::isValue() { //at this point if I called this it would 
    return value;     //return true as expected.
}
```

The header for class Foo:

```
class Bar;

class Foo {
private:
  Bar* barPtr; //a pointer to class Bar.

public:
  void readValue(); 
};
```

and the source file:

```
void Foo::readValue() {
   cout << barPtr->isValue(); //pointer that accesses and displays value. 
}
```

This last step is where I run into the problem. The value returned is 0, false, and I don't understand why exactly. When I call  cout << barPtr->isValue() in my main it returns the correct value true. The only thing I could think of is maybe I need a copy constructor? If that is the case I'm not entirely sure how to go about implementing that for this situation.

Thank you!

Comment: You are not setting `value` anywhere, so its value is indeterminate.

Comment: Do you understand the concept of being private?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What's happening is that you're not initializing the value of `value` in your constructor for `Bar`.  So the value it starts out with is basically whatever is randomly at on the stack where it's constructed -- the value is indeterminate and can change from run to run.

Fix this by initializing `value` in your `Bar` constructor, for example defining a constructor such as:

```
Bar::Bar()
    : value(false) {}
```

Declare it accordingly in your class declaration and you should be set.

Answer (score 1):

You are not initializing pointer to `Bar` object nor its value. You need to initialize the pointer by a valid object and then set its value to get it true. Also, if required, initialize default value in constructor of `Bar`.